# How to get rid of whitespace under a collapsed container using GXT?

Tags: java, gxt

I'm currently trying to work with a fieldset in java GXT.  I've made the fieldset collapsible but the result is the fieldset collapses but the other containers don't come together to close the space.  The height of the fieldset is how big the whitespace is left after the fieldset is collapsed.

```
final FieldSet rulesFieldSet = new FieldSet();
hlc.add(gridPanel, new HorizontalLayoutData(-1, 200));
    2ndContainer.add(hlc, 
            new VerticalLayoutData(-1, -1, new Margins(4, 4, 4, 4)));
    fieldSet.add(rulesContainer);
    fieldSet.setHeight(250);
    fieldSet.setCollapsible(true);
    mainLayoutContainer.add(rulesFieldSet, 
            new VerticalLayoutData(-1, -1, new Margins(15, 0, 0, 35)));
```

I've tried adding a collapse handler to hide/remove the children of fieldset to no avail.  Huge thank you to anyone that helps or can give advice to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the other fields to follow the collapse/expansion of the fieldset, you should set the height of the layout of parent container in which you are adding the fieldset and other containers to -1.